# Php.ini production vs development

Tags: php

I'm using XAMPP to develop on my localhost.  I would like to remove the PHP notices and keep only the warnings.  I know this is done through the `php.ini` file, however I'm having trouble locating it.  I followed the path in `phpinfo()` and it led me to `/xampp/php`. Inside this folder are two `php.ini` files: one for production and one for development.  I have set them both to the error reporting level I'd like, however I still receive notices which makes me believe that neither of these actually control error reporting.  I'm using the latest version of XAMPP.  So I guess my question is where is the true `php.ini` and what are these two other versions?

Comment: The default php.ini location should be `xampp/php/php.ini`. If you've edited that and it isn't working, what values are you using for each?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, make sure you're editing `php.ini`, not `php-development.ini` or `php-production.ini` or anything BUT **`php.ini`**.  After that, ensure you restart your Apache server or your changes won't take effect.

Also, check out [ini_set](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) for setting ini values at runtime.

Answer (score 43):

As of PHP 7 the regular php.ini file was removed and added with php.ini-production and php.ini-devlopment. In PHP's installation text file they state, "We advise you to use php.ini-production, because we optimized the default settings in this file for performance, and security."

**So in short use the php.ini-production**

Comment: Thanks for the hint. So no `cp php.ini-production php.ini` needed?

Comment: @daniel, just the opposite actually. The only usable filename (unless specifying a custom php config/ini filename in apache configuration or on the command line) is `php.ini`. So you will need to copy `php.ini-production` to `php.ini` in order to get started. The php website and this comment from @Dalton are just suggesting you use the production-minded file rather than the development-minded file. In reality, if you're developing in xampp, you probably want the development ini file because it's tuned for behaviors that are helpful during development.

Comment: Completely wrong answer.

Answer (score 7):

I had this confusion, in my computer, the php.ini file didn't appear with the .ini extension name visible - it was just php , and in the type column, it has the value 'configuration settings'

Comment: Yes - this is the problem: on Windows with XAMPP, when you look in the PHP dir, you don't see php.ini. just php.ini-development and php.ini-production, which are different.  Thank you for clarifying that "php is, in fact, php.ini.

Answer (score 6):

I downloaded php-8.1.0 from official website. `php.ini` or `configuration settings` file is not present in it. Instead it has been replaced by two files i.e. `php.ini-development` and `php.ini-production`.

My requirement was to edit the `php.ini` file in order to enable pgsql extension. Alas! there were not one but two `.ini` files. Being new to php, I made changes to both the files but it didn't worked.

After doing some research, I came to know that in the recent versions of php (not sure from which), user is provided with two `.ini` files. As name suggests, `php.ini-development` contains settings suitable for development environment and `php.ini-production` contains settings suitable for production environment. As per your requirement, you need take backup of anyone of the file and rename that file to `php.ini`. In this file you will need make required changes for your php environment.

If you compare the two files using tools such as diff-merge, you will get more in-depth understanding.

Answer (score 2):

`php.ini.development` and `php.ini.production` are entirely different from `php.ini`.
the problem is that in the php folder the required `php.ini` is not marked along with its extension ( `.php`). Only php is written.Check the properties of the file '`php`' of "`*configuration settings*`" type.it must be `.ini`,This is the exact file which manages error reporting.

Answer (score 0):

In XAMPP version 1.8.1 php.ini file located at \xampp\php\php.ini modify line 922 upload_max_filesize = 2M 
Note: 2M means 2MB, so change to 10M for 10MB file upload. Also note that php.ini-development and php.ini-production are different files from php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

My issue is that I was editing the `php.ini-production` and overlooked the standard `php.ini` file.

I edited the `php.ini` file by adding `extension=php_odbc.dll` and it fixed the error.

Answer (score -2):

PHP 5.3.0 has significantly improved performance and parsing of INI files, and adds several new syntax features.

The standard php.ini files have been re-organized and renamed. php.ini-development contains settings recommended for use in development environments. php.ini-production contains settings recommended for use in production environments

Answer (score -2):

The PHP.ini file is still there, only it doesn't include the extension .ini, the extension has been removed. You will notice two file name php, one is application file another is configuration setting when you open configuration setting in notepad you will notice that it has ini extension. so the php configuration file is ini file.