# Composer error prevents laravel installation

Tags: laravel, composer-php

This annoying problem happened, when I just wanted to install laravel to continue coding. However, I run into these errors, any ideas? I've got PHP already by the way.

EDIT: as for that "duplicate", my problem is that it outputs "You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled." when I tried the answer in that question which is "composer config -g -- disable-tls true"

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249620/the-openssl-extension-is-required-for-ssl-tls-protection)

Comment: it still gives the same error when i entered "composer config -g -- disable-tls true"

Comment: "You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled." is the result

Comment: are you able to `ping packagist.org`?

Comment: yes i can ping packagist.org