# Laravel failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8000 (reason ?)

Tags: laravel-8

[image]

So I just created a new project using the command:

```
laravel new blog
```

Then I  started by changing the directory and do the command

```
php artisan serve
```

And this is what happened, more details:

1. I'm using laravel 8.0.1 (latest version)
2. I haven't run any command except the one I listed above
3. I'm using windows
4. I even updated the php to 7.4.10 (latest ver)

Comment: You don't have php.ini or not good configured.
You can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52594477/composer-not-working-on-windows-gives-composer-exception-nosslexception-error/61361052/#answer-61361052)

Comment: Loaded Configuration File:         C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.9\php.ini
same problem

Answer (score 14):

I came across the same issue.
This was how how I solved mine:

1. Goto the main PHP part, I mean the installed PHP from official website.
2. Look out for a folder named `php.ini-development`
3. Duplicate this file.
4. Then rename the copy to `php.ini`
5. Go back to your laravel project folder and rerun `php artisan serve`

PS: If there is any additional steps you took, you can as well comment them below:
XOXO

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too, and I solved it in this way:

```
set: php.ini

variables_order = "GPCS"
```

Answer (score 1):

So actually i dont actually know what the reason is, but using the php -S localhost:8000 -t public

Answer (score 0):

Check your PHP version in your local server and System variable path. Make sure they are using the same PHP version

Answer (score 0):

This error is because the php.ini was not found.

run php --ini

Configuration File (php.ini) Path:
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\php8\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

The line "Loaded Configuration File" would indicate the location of loaded php.ini, if not, rename the php.ini-development to php.ini