# php.ini Development v/s Production using dockerfile

Tags: php, docker, yii, dockerfile

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880749/php-ini-production-vs-development) is a similar question. However I am using dockerfile to automate `php init` and I am unsure as to how to choose a default environment i.e. production or development when doing a `docker build`. My dockerfile is as

```
RUN npm install -g grunt-cli \
&& grunt \
&& curl --silent --show-error https://getcomposer.org/installer | php   \
&& php composer.phar \
&& php init
```

On building the dockerfile the `RUN` will execute php init and move to the next step as it receives no input. Here's the log:

```
Yii Application Initialization Tool v1.0

Which environment do you want the application to be initialized in?

[0] Development
[1] Production

Your choice [0-1, or "q" to quit] 
Quit initialization.
Removing intermediate container 8f33b171f111
---> 83cb0a4ee43e
Step 33/35 : EXPOSE 8080
```

How to automatically pass a value so that it does not quit?

Comment: define a an environment variable called `env` with value `Production`, https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/init#L23

Comment: or do `php init --env=Production --overwrite=y`

Comment: The second option worked. However, can you please tell me what exactly does the first one do. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry the first one what? a docker environment? or the source code which shows the bash script which your running?

Comment: The source code for the script. From what I understand it is checking which environment to run and then doing the appropriate tasks.

Comment: Yeah exactly, and by predefining an env variable or `--env=Production` it will know what to do. Sorry, I thought it was bash originally its php though ;p