# Should I use a Production or Development environment in PHP?

Tags: php, production-environment

How do I configure PHP to either use a production environment or a development environment in PHP 5.5.x?

In order for the errors that I want to display, I've un-commented `'Production Value: On'` underneath the `display_errors` section, and `'Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT'` underneath the `error_reporting` section.

However, what determines production vs. development? Is it a setting in `php.ini`, or somewhere else?

Edit: This is for my `php.ini` file. Perhaps I wasn't clear with my question. Currently, if I want my errors to display or not, I toggle the Production Value on or off.

So, in which case would I ever toggle the `Development Value` settings on or off? And what settings would determine (and where would it be determined) that the `Development Value` settings would be useful as opposed to the `Production Value` settings? (Hopefully this is clear, I'm not sure how else I can word it.)

Comment: There is no such setting as `Production Value` in default PHP configuration settings

Comment: this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880749/php-ini-production-vs-development

Answer (score 0):

There are some values - like your mentioned ones - that you don't want to be enabled on a live system, for various reasons (security, speed, performance).

I think you have something else in mind. Some frameworks and tools (Magento 2, symfony, Laravel) can use different settings for different environments.

For example: on a dev server, you would like to enable debugging information, that might slow down your application a bit. On live you would like to debug less things.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/environments.html